# Looking for spatial panel data package (Not R!)

Tags: package

I am looking for a package for spatial panel data analysis (Econometrics). That does not use R!

Answer (score 2):

- [XSMLE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjr-Iz-3tf5AhVLJrkGHVyYAZIQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.sagepub.com%2Fdoi%2Fpdf%2F10.1177%2F1536867X1701700109&usg=AOvVaw3aLuqUKfr_h2fb4-6H5WZs) on `STATA`
- [Pysal](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjzhcan39f5AhWmDrkGHYSbDg4QFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpysal.org%2Fspreg%2Fnotebooks%2FPanel_FE_example.html&usg=AOvVaw3Z-QLO_ap6s5ur89LGT6az) on `Python`
- [Spatial-Panels](https://spatial-panels.com/?page_id=2) on `MATLAB`